# Why is Premiere Pro playback slower then Windows Media Player?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, adobe-premiere, adobe-cs6

I have installed Premiere Pro CS6 on my home workstation (RENDER-PC). When I log in using RDP from my laptop (DAVID-LAPTOP), the audio and video stutter (oddly, they are in sync, they just stutter).

When I export the video (720p, 5 Minutes, 29.97 FPS, encoded as an AVI, NTSC DV Preset), it renders perfectly in under 2 minutes.

**If I play it back in Windows Media Player, it plays back fine.**

What is the reason for this? Its the same video, just in different programs.

EDIT: This also happens if you play a video in Chrome. It stutters, but downloading the same video plays back fine in Media Player.

EDIT2: [Here are the Export settings in Premiere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nocYc.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[Not entirely sure about the details](https://superuser.com/posts/881168/edit), but Windows Media Player is likely using the video streaming option of recent RDP protocol versions – it reads the compressed video file and tells the OS to stream it over RDP directly, having the *client* decompress and render it.

Meanwhile, other programs (unaware of RDP) render it server-side, causing *each individual frame* to be transmitted over RDP, *decompressed*. This obviously requires far more bandwidth (that's why the original video was compressed in the first place), causing some frames to be dropped.

---

(RDP does have some compression, but it uses different algorithms. It's optimized for program interfaces which have quite different requirements; loss-less since you wouldn't want a program to appear blurry; transferring frames in 256x256 tiles instead of whole frame; and so on. It doesn't work well for video.)

Comment: Well this makes sense. Is there any way to make Premiere stream its video the same way as WMP?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what activates the RDP video streaming, maybe it just depends on the program using DXVA for hardware acceleration, but that's still something each program's developers have to consider. I'm sure, however, that in the end it relies on the program giving the OS the original video. (The OS won't try to magically detect and "re-compress" it.)